# Using the FreeType lib to create text bitmaps to draw in OpenGL 3.x

Tags: c++, opengl, fonts, textures

At the moment I not too sure where my problem is. I can draw loaded images as textures no problem, however when I try to generate a bitmap with a char on it I just get a black box.

I am confident that the problem is when I generate and upload the texture.

Here is the method for that; the top section of the if statement just draws an texture of a image loaded from file (res/texture.jpg) and that draws perfectly. And the else part of the if statement will try to generate and upload a texture with the char (variable char enter) on.

[image: output]

Source Code, I will add shaders and more of the C++ if needed but they work fine for the image.

```
    void uploadTexture()
    {
        if(enter=='/'){

            // Draw the image.
            GLenum imageFormat;
            glimg::SingleImage image = glimg::loaders::stb::LoadFromFile("res/texture.jpg")->GetImage(0,0,0);
            glimg::OpenGLPixelTransferParams params =  glimg::GetUploadFormatType(image.GetFormat(), 0);
            imageFormat = glimg::GetInternalFormat(image.GetFormat(),0);

            glGenTextures(1,&textureBufferObject);
            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureBufferObject);

            glimg::Dimensions dimensions = image.GetDimensions();
            cout << "Texture dimensions w "<< dimensions.width << endl;
            glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB8, dimensions.width, dimensions.height, 0, params.format, params.type, image.GetImageData());
        }else
        {
            // Draw the char useing the FreeType Lib
            FT_Init_FreeType(&ft);
            FT_New_Face(ft, "arial.ttf", 0, &face);
            FT_Set_Pixel_Sizes(face, 0, 48);

            FT_GlyphSlot g = face->glyph;


            glGenTextures(1,&textureBufferObject);
            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureBufferObject);

            glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);

            FT_Load_Char(face, enter, FT_LOAD_RENDER);
            FT_Bitmap theBitmap = g->bitmap;

            int BitmapWidth = g->bitmap.width;
            int BitmapHeight = g->bitmap.rows;



            cout << "draw char - " << enter << endl;
            cout << "g->bitmap.width - " << g->bitmap.width << endl;
            cout << "g->bitmap.rows - " << g->bitmap.rows << endl;

            int TextureWidth =roundUpToNextPowerOfTwo(g->bitmap.width);
            int TextureHeight =roundUpToNextPowerOfTwo(g->bitmap.rows);

            cout << "texture width x height - " << TextureWidth <<" x " << TextureHeight << endl;

            GLubyte* TextureBuffer = new GLubyte[ TextureWidth * TextureWidth ];
            for(int j = 0; j < TextureHeight; ++j)
            {
                for(int i = 0; i < TextureWidth; ++i)
                {
                    TextureBuffer[ j*TextureWidth + i ] = (j >= BitmapHeight || i >= BitmapWidth ? 0 : g->bitmap.buffer[ j*BitmapWidth + i ]);
                }
            }

            glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB8, TextureWidth, TextureHeight, 0, GL_RGB8, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, TextureBuffer);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Just to double-check:  You're using the same codepath that renders `GL_RGB8` textures fine with a `GL_ALPHA` texture and you're wondering why you aren't getting any color?

Comment: I've changed them to GL_RGB8 like the image is however I as still faced with the issue. I will edit that on the above post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure about the OpenGL part, but your algorithm to process FT bitmap is not correct. The number of bytes of each row in FT bitmap is `bitmap->pitch`. The number of each pixel also depends on which render mode your are loading the character. For example, if `bitmap->pixel_mode` is `FT_PIXEL_MODE_LCD`, each pixel is encoded as 3 bytes, in order of R, G, B and the values are actually the alpha mask value, while if the pixel mode is `FT_PIXEL_MODE_GRAY`, each pixel is 1 byte and the values are the gray level.

Take a look at http://freetype.sourceforge.net/freetype2/docs/reference/ft2-basic_types.html#FT_Bitmap

Comment: Even with that been the case, surely I would expect even a skewed texture outputted.

Comment: Have you checked the buffer in FT bitmap? Are they zeros?

Comment: No I havent looked at that, I guess that will show which side the problem is on.. thanks for the idea.! and other replys.

Comment: The output from running a loop to print the rows of the bitmap was sort of surprising. I entered K on the left and W on the right. http://i.imgur.com/eafh7.png. I know im not printing that out right but this sort of freaked me out.

Comment: Could you tell me what is your pixel_mode? The "w" case shows that you are not using `FT_PIXEL_MODE_LCD`, otherwise bitmap->width should always be a multiple of 3. However, your OpenGL code uses GL_RGB8, which is 24-bit pixel. The output is OK, since there could be unprintable characters.

Comment: Then the RGB bytes of each pixel should be assigned to the same gray level, and the GLubyte buffer needs at least `3 * texture_width * texture_height`. Pad the row bytes if necessary. Do not allocate it as `texture_width * texture_width`. You will overflow the buffer and writes to unallocated area.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12718/discussion-between-andy-and-crend-king)

Comment: Got it working now, it was just the image format was wrong. The algorithm was fine. http://i.imgur.com/C4I39.png - so basicly once I buffered the Texture up as RGB it was all good.

Answer (score 0):

The very first thing I'd do would be to look at the return codes that Freetype gives to pretty much ALL the FT_* functions.

That's good practice anyway, but if you have a problem it should narrow it down substantially.